# Как передать аргументы в callback функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент react `App`. Он принимает объект `settingsObj`с callbac функцией:

```
export const settingsObj = {
  handlers: {
    onClick: (e, dispatch) => {
      console.log('сработал клик из settingsObj', e);
      dispatch('привет из dispatch');
    }
  }
}
```

объединяет его функционал с функционалом callbac который находится в `handlers` внутри компонента `App`
при помощи функции `concatenatesEventHandlers` и получившийся callbac присваивает кнопке `button`.

```
const concatenatesEventHandlers = (
  ownedEventHandlers,
  addedEventHandlers,
  dispatch
) => {
  const _ownedEventHandlers = { ...ownedEventHandlers };
  if (!addedEventHandlers || Object.keys(addedEventHandlers).length === 0) {
    return _ownedEventHandlers;
  }
  const keyAddedEventHandlers = Object.keys(addedEventHandlers);
  // функция объединяет функционал обработчиков (собственного и переданного eventHandlers)
  for (const handl in ownedEventHandlers) {
    if (ownedEventHandlers.hasOwnProperty(handl)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < keyAddedEventHandlers.length; i++) {
        if (handl === keyAddedEventHandlers[i]) {
          const concatFunc = (e, dispatch) => {
            ownedEventHandlers[handl]();
            addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]](e, dispatch);
          };
          _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e, dispatch) =>
            concatFunc(e, dispatch);
        } else {
          _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] =
            addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return _ownedEventHandlers;
};
```

Код на codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sun-wgtn4h?file=/src/data.js

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пытаюсь передать функцию для callbac из `settingsObj`, в данном случае `dispatch`, то она (dispatch) всегда `undefined` внутри callbac в объекте `settingsObj`. Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся?

PS ошибка появляется при клике на кнопку "кликни меня".

Comment: в коде по ссылке не задан `settingsObj`

Comment: Спасибо что подсказали. Заменил ссылку. Сейчас все норм.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код функции `concatenatesEventHandlers`

Comment: Код добавил. Так же он ещё представлен на codesandbox по ссылке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если убрать лишний код станет заметно, что параметр `dispatch` нигде не используется

```
const concatenatesEventHandlers = (
  ownedEventHandlers,
  addedEventHandlers,
  dispatch
) => {
  ...
  const concatFunc = (e, dispatch) => {
    ownedEventHandlers[handl]();
    addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]](e, dispatch);
  };
  _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e, dispatch) =>
  concatFunc(e, dispatch);
  ...
};
```

Чтобы стало еще понятнее, достаточно переименовать параметр

```
const concatenatesEventHandlers = (
  ownedEventHandlers,
  addedEventHandlers,
  dispatch
) => {
  ...
  const concatFunc = (e, secondArg) => {
    ownedEventHandlers[handl]();
    addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]](e, secondArg);
  };
  _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e, secondArg) =>
  concatFunc(e, secondArg);
  ...
};
```

Для решения достаточно удалить лишний параметр из добавляемых обработчиков, в этом случае будет замыкаться параметр приходящий в функцию `concatenatesEventHandlers`

```
const concatenatesEventHandlers = (
  ownedEventHandlers,
  addedEventHandlers,
  dispatch
) => {
  ...
  const concatFunc = (e) => {
    ownedEventHandlers[handl]();
    addedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]](e, dispatch);
  };
  _ownedEventHandlers[keyAddedEventHandlers[i]] = (e) =>
  concatFunc(e, dispatch);
  ...
};
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Твой ответ мне очень помог.